# Do (co)density (co)monadic constructions stablize?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, monads, kan-extension

Under good conditions [1], any functor $F: C \to D$ induces a codensity monad $T: D \to D$ as a right Kan extension of $F$ along itself. It does not say explicitly, but by considering left/right Kan extension/lift, it could make sense to talk about four variants: (co)density (co)monads. These subsume many natural mathematical constructions [1].

Taking composites, e.g. $TF: C \to D$, **we get four natural new functors of the same type for free**! And since $TF$ is a functor, we can construct its (co)density (co)monads iteratively.

**Question**

1. Does such iterative construction stablize?
2. If not, what's the state of the art about it?

**Reference**

- [1] https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/09/where_do_monads_come_from.html

Comment: I can't write an answer. Google for "Structure-Semantics adjunction".

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti thanks for your comment! Would you be more specific about it? I don't see how it relates to stability..

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about state of the art, but here are a couple of comments.

As is pointed out in your reference, if $F$ has a left adjoint $G$, then $T=FG$. If $F$ happens to be fully faithful, then $G$ is a localization functor. In this case $TF\cong F$, so the construction stabilizes. This holds regardless of whether $F$ has a left adjoint: if $F$ is fully faithful embedding then $TF=F$.

But if $F$ is just a functor with a left adjoint, there is no reason for the construction to stabilize. What happens is that $F$ induces a functor from $C$ to the category of $T$-algebras (which is usually denoted by the same letter $F$). The functor $F$ is called *monadic* if this induced functor is an equivalence of categories. Beck's monadicity theorem gives a criterion that characterizes monadic functors.

Perhaps more relevant to "state of the art", in the last decade there has been an interest in homotopic analogues of this set-up, e.g. in the context of Quillen model categories or $\infty$-categories. You can read more about it for example in the chapter Monads and the Barr-Beck Theorem in Lurie's Higher Algebra. I also recommend [these notes](https://nilesjohnson.net/research/UGA-descent-notes.pdf) on homotopic descent.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. That F being fully faithful stabilizes this process is helpful. I'd have to get familiar with the language of Lurie's HA to get my hands on it. Is it about the homotopic analogue of monadicity theorem? Or is it about the stabilizing problem I posed?

Comment: It is about the monadicity theorem, not the stabilization question.